# how to enhanced query mongodb slow

Tags: mongodb

I've got a MongoDB collection that when queried takes 8-10 seconds.

There are some indexes set, here's the output of `db.notif.getIndexes();`

```
db.notif.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_",
                "ns" : "testing.notif"
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "unique" : true,
                "key" : {
                        "id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "id_1",
                "ns" : "testing.notif",
                "background" : true
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "deleted" : 1
                },
                "name" : "deleted_1",
                "ns" : "testing.notif",
                "background" : true
        },
        {
                "v" : 2,
                "key" : {
                        "__ttl" : 1
                },
                "name" : "__ttl_1",
                "ns" : "testing.notif",
                "background" : true
        }
]
```

When I execute this query

```
db.notif.find({
  "mobile": "6281388756078",
  "paytest.type": { "$in": ["IKLAN","INFO","WEB"] }
}).explain("executionStats")
```

it takes over 8-9 seconds. Do I need to enhanced the query or add further indexing?

Comment: It looks like your query is likely performing a collection scan because there is no index on 'mobile' or 'playtest.type'. Ideally there should be a compound index on both of those fields. Could you add the results of the explain query? I could  help to interpret the results.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are filtering on two fields - "mobile" and "paytest.type". You have created 4 indexes but none of them are on these two fields.

Add index either on one of them (having better cardinality) or a compound index on both the fields.

From the general perspective, the mobile field looks better option for index. Try this:

```
db.notif.createIndex({ "mobile": 1 });
```